# In Oscar, what is a line?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm using the ecommerce package Django-Oscar. In Oscar there is an object related to Basket called a "Line" that I do not understand. What is a Line, what information does it convey and what is it meant to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Django-Oscar for 2 years. It was the very raw package.
A line is one record in the Basket.
You can see it in source model AbstractLine.

```
class AbstractLine(models.Model):
    """
    A line of a basket (product and a quantity)
    """
    basket = models.ForeignKey('basket.Basket', related_name='lines',
                               verbose_name=_("Basket"))
```

```
# This is to determine which products belong to the same line
# We can't just use product.id as you can have customised products
# which should be treated as separate lines.  Set as a
# SlugField as it is included in the path for certain views.
line_reference = models.SlugField(_("Line Reference"), max_length=128,
                                  db_index=True)

product = models.ForeignKey(
    'catalogue.Product', related_name='basket_lines',
    verbose_name=_("Product"))
quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Quantity'), default=1)

# We store the unit price incl tax of the product when it is first added to
# the basket.  This allows us to tell if a product has changed price since
# a person first added it to their basket.
price_excl_tax = models.DecimalField(
    _('Price excl. Tax'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12,
    null=True)
price_incl_tax = models.DecimalField(
    _('Price incl. Tax'), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, null=True)
# Track date of first addition
date_created = models.DateTimeField(_("Date Created"), auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an item in the basket:

```
int single word "BasketItem"
""" product and a quantity """
```

Ref: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/basket/abstract_models.py#L564